# scala call-by-name - declaring parameters that aren't used

Tags: scala

One of the benefits of call-by-name is that expensiveOperation() will not get run in the following examples:

Call-by-value:

```
def test( x: Int, y: Int ): Int = x * x

// expensiveOperation is evaluated and the result passed to test()
test( 4, expensiveOperation() )
```

Call-by-name:

```
def test( x: Int, y: => Int ): Int = x * x

// expensionOperation is not evaluated
test( 4, expensiveOperation() )
```

My question though is why would you declare a function parameter (y in my case) when you aren't going to use it?

Comment: Then do not take `y` as argument? What is it that you want

Comment: Exactly!  I am just repeating the example given in the functional programming course by Martin Odersky - https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is a bit contrived, consider this code

```
def test( x: Boolean, y: => Int ): Int = if(x) y else 0

// expensionOperation is not evaluated
test( false, expensiveOperation() )
```

When the first parameter is false you are saving a lot of time not evaluating expensive operation.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a contrived example to illustrate the idea of call-by-name, namely that the argument passed in is never evaluated if never called.

Perhaps a better example would be the following:

```
trait Option[+T] {
    def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B
}
```

If the `Option` is `Some`, then the wrapped value is returned and `default` is never evaluated. If it is `None` and only when it is `None` will `default` be evaluated (and consequently returned).

Answer (score 2):

Using logging is a much better example:

```
def debug(msg: String) = if (logging.enabled) println(msg)

debug(slowStatistics()) // slowStatistics will always be evaluated
```

While in the case of call-by-name:

```
def debug(msg: => String) = if (logging.enabled) println(msg)

debug(slowStatistics()) // slowStatistics will be evaluated only if logging.enabled
```

Comment: The problem with using by-name formal parameters in logging is that quite often they make it *more* expensive. E.g., a common use such as `logger.debug("Made it")` requires instantiation of the compiler-generated thunk class just to hold what is effectively a compile-time constant (whether `debug` level is enabled or not).

Comment: @RandallSchulz Sadly, true. The by-name parameter is captured via a relatively expensive closure.